# How to add list of unique models to a django model

Tags: django, django-models, mariadb

I am developing a dashboard app for clients to manage their devices with django and mariadb database. I have a Client model (which is the extended user model) and Device model which represents single, unique device. One user can have multiple devices, but one device can be assigned to only one user.

Now, what is the best way to create an entry in Client model, that will contain all his assigned devices. What is important, one device (represented by unique device id) can appear only once in all `Client.devices` tables.

Here is the code to visualize my problem:

```python
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    devices = <?>


class Device(models.Model):
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0x00)
    id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True, default=0x00)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I feel like the answer is out there, but I'm not sure that other similar topics would match my uniqueness

Comment: You don't need to create a separate field for this, If you want to access all devices related to a particular client, you can do it by calling `.device_set.all()` on an instance of a `Client` object. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

Comment: where `device_set` is...?

Comment: This is added automatically by django to all instances of the `Client` model

Comment: That's very useful, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved by @Ersain D. It turns out I don't need a separate field, just a `.device_set.all()` query on instance of Client object

Answer (score 0):

Django has `distinct()` clause for queries. To get a distinct devices assigned to client try this:

```
unique_devices = Device.objects.filter(user=client.user).distinct()
```

Here are official docs on [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

Comment: Probably trivial question but I'm quite new to both django and databases. I don't really understand how does it differ from just `Device.objects.filter(user=client.user)` ?

Comment: Your device model has many-to-one relationship with user, meaning that user can have multiple devices. There might be several instances of devices that point to the same user. If you do not use distinct you will get all devices that point to that user.